How can I use COUNTIF and FILTER functions to get a count for the output array?
I have used this function to get how many times a specific input occurred in 3 shifts "M, E and N"
=COUNTA(FILTER(FILTER(Input!$D$3:$E$95,(Input!$D$3:$D$95=Nurses!A2)*(Input!$E$3:$E$95="E")),{0,1}))

So basically, I got the result as 4 when using COUNTA however if the FILTER gives and ERROR message, It turns that COUNTA considers it as a value of 1 which is absolutely not the fact.
I tried to replace COUNTA with COUNTIF
=COUNTIF(FILTER(FILTER(Input!$D$3:$E$95,(Input!$D$3:$D$95=Nurses!A2)*(Input!$E$3:$E$95="E")),{0,1}),"E")

the whole function doesn't run and I keep getting an Error message.
I decided to used IFERROR and IF
=IF(IFERROR(FILTER(FILTER(Input!$D$3:$E$95,(Input!$D$3:$D$95=Nurses!A2)*(Input!$E$3:$E$95="E")),{0,1}),0)=0,0,COUNTA(FILTER(FILTER(Input!$D$3:$E$95,(Input!$D$3:$D$95=Nurses!A2)*(Input!$E$3:$E$95="E")),{0,1})))

The output was an array of 4 times the number of E appearance in the FILTER function.
I hope that someone can help with this simple issue, I am so thankful in adavnce.
I tried
Filter, IFERROR, IF, COUNT, COUNTA, COUNTIF

please see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.  Also check out the tour, and help center

May be you can use something like this : =SUM(1-ISERROR(N(FILTER(Input!$E$3:$E$95,(Input!$D$3:$D$95=Nurses!A2)*(Input!$E$3:$E$95="E"))<>"")))


the whole function doesn't run and I keep getting an Error message.  COUNTIF does not take arrays as the first parameter; use of FILTER results in array and thus the error message.


Is it a one-off task or ongoing one? If it is the latter, I would suggest naming ranges and pulling data together and use Pivot Tables. https://exceljet.net/articles/named-ranges

Appreciated! I am not considering myself and expert in Excel but It's just a one time fixed task. I will try to go with naming as yours works perfectly as the final one I got specially to not include the empty cells.

You could use:
=IFERROR(ROWS(FILTER(Input!$E$3:$E$95,(Input!$D$3:$D$95=Nurses!A2)*(Input!$E$3:$E$95="E"))),0)

